# is it possible to constrain number of variables randomly using Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: python

I am using genetic algorithm to optimization. I have 13 variables and trying to find coefficients for each variable, so I define boundary of (-1,1) for each coefficient variable. But I'd like to constraint only 3-4 variable coefficients(randomly) were chosen each iteration while keeping the rest of coefficient to be zero. How to add constraint to GA?

```
from geneticalgorithm import geneticalgorithm as ga

varbound=np.array([[0.0,0.0]]*len(x_coef))

varbound[:,0]=-1; 
varbound[:,1]=1    

algorithm_param={'max_num_iteration': None, 'population_size':100,   #None
'mutation_probability':0.1,'elit_ratio': 0.1,
'crossover_probability': 0.5,'parents_portion': 0.2,
'crossover_type':'uniform','max_iteration_without_improv':100}

model=ga(function=f,dimension=len(x_coef),variable_type='real',
         variable_boundaries=varbound, algorithm_parameters=algorithm_param)

model.run()
convergence=model.report
solution=model.output_dict
```

Comment: Even if you can't find a way to constrain some parameters from outside, you can add penalty points for them in fitness function when they go outside of the limits. A linearly dependent penalty value should make the ga choose values within limits. Something like error+=distance_from_limit_point.

Comment: Thank you huseyin, good point to use penalty. any example on input in the function parameter? Thanks